# Is Delaunay triangulation unique for a given set of points

Tags: triangulation

For a given set of points in the 3D space or in a 2D space, can two different triangulation that conform to the Delanuay rules of empty circumcirle be created? If yes what would it depend on, the starting point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Delaunay triangulation is unique iff the circumcircle of every triangle contains exactly three points on its circumference: the vertices of the triangle.

For instance, the Delaunay diagram of the four vertices of a square is a square, and can be converted into a triangulation in two different ways.

Comment: in the [constrained Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation) it says "Delaunay triangulation is almost always unique" but there is no reference. Can you refer to that too? many thanks

Comment: @Rott, "almost always" means that the probability of four points to be cocircular is zero.